# Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'DelonModule' was called

Tags: angular, webpack

The `DelonModule` is a third file.It has many functions to help development,such as `ACL` `auth` etc.

The point is,I packed up it normally several days ago.But somehow it report the error `ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'DelonModule' was called.` when I input the command `ng build`.

Code of `delon.module.ts` as below(`core code`)

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    NgZorroAntdModule.forRoot(),
    NgZorroAntdExtraModule.forRoot(),
    // theme
    AlainThemeModule.forRoot(),
    // abc
    AdErrorCollectModule.forRoot(), AdFooterToolbarModule.forRoot(), AdSidebarNavModule.forRoot(), AdDownFileModule.forRoot(), AdImageModule.forRoot(),
    AdAvatarListModule.forRoot(), AdDescListModule.forRoot(), AdEllipsisModule.forRoot(), AdExceptionModule.forRoot(), AdExceptionModule.forRoot(),
    AdNoticeIconModule.forRoot(), AdNumberInfoModule.forRoot(), AdProHeaderModule.forRoot(), AdResultModule.forRoot(), AdStandardFormRowModule.forRoot(),
    AdTagSelectModule.forRoot(), AdTrendModule.forRoot(), AdUtilsModule.forRoot(), AdChartsModule.forRoot(), AdCountDownModule.forRoot(), AdSimpleTableModule.forRoot(),
    AdReuseTabModule.forRoot(),
    AdFullContentModule.forRoot(), AdXlsxModule.forRoot(), AdZipModule.forRoot(),
    // auth
    AlainAuthModule.forRoot({
        // 受限于 https://github.com/cipchk/ng-alain/issues/246， 只支持字符串形式
        // ignores: [ `\\/login`, `assets\\/` ],
        login_url: `/passport/login`
    }),
    // acl
    AlainACLModule.forRoot(),
    // cache
    DelonCacheModule.forRoot()
   ]
 })
    export class DelonModule {
     constructor(@Optional() @SkipSelf() parentModule: DelonModule) {
    throwIfAlreadyLoaded(parentModule, 'DelonModule');
}

static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    const _NZ_MESSAGE_CONFIG = {
        nzDuration: 1500,
        nzMaxStack: 1,
        nzPauseOnHover: true,
        nzAnimate: true
    };
    return {
        ngModule: DelonModule,
        providers: [
            { provide: NZ_MESSAGE_CONFIG, useValue: _NZ_MESSAGE_CONFIG },
            { provide: DA_STORE_TOKEN, useClass: SessionStorageStore }
            // TIPS：@delon/abc 有大量的全局配置信息，例如设置所有 `simple-table` 的页码默认为 `20` 行
            // { provide: SimpleTableConfig, useFactory: simpleTableConfig }
        ]
    };
}
}
```

Code of `app.module.ts` as below

```
    import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID, APP_INITIALIZER, Injector } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

    import { DelonModule } from './delon.module';
    import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
    import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { RoutesModule } from './routes/routes.module';
    import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
    import { StartupService } from '@core/startup/startup.service';
    import { DefaultInterceptor } from '@core/net/default.interceptor';
    import { SimpleInterceptor } from '@delon/auth';
    import { DA_STORE_TOKEN } from '@delon/auth';
    // ngx-cookie
    import { CookieModule } from 'ngx-cookie';
    // angular i18n
    import { registerLocaleData, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
    import localeZhHans from '@angular/common/locales/zh-Hans';
    registerLocaleData(localeZhHans);
    // i18n
    import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
    import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
    import { ALAIN_I18N_TOKEN } from '@delon/theme';
    import { I18NService } from '@core/i18n/i18n.service';

    // AoT requires an exported function for factories
    export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
        return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, `assets/i18n/`, '.json');
    }

    // JSON-Schema form
    import { JsonSchemaModule } from '@shared/json-schema/json-schema.module';

    export function StartupServiceFactory(startupService: StartupService): Function {
        return () => startupService.load();
    }

    // import { CookieModule, CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';
    import { ReuseTabService } from '@delon/abc/reuse-tab/reuse-tab.service';
    import { Logger, Options } from 'angular2-logger/core';
    import { isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            BrowserAnimationsModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            DelonModule.forRoot(),
            CoreModule,
            SharedModule,
            LayoutModule,
            JsonSchemaModule,
            RoutesModule,
            // ngx-cookie
            CookieModule.forRoot(),
            // i18n
            TranslateModule.forRoot({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                    deps: [HttpClient]
                }
            })
        ],
        providers: [/* 
            Logger,
            { provide: Options, useValue: { level: environment.logger, store: true } }, */
            Logger,
            Options,
            DatePipe,
            { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'zh-Hans' },
            // { provide: DA_STORE_TOKEN, useClass: CookieStorage, multi: false },  // 在此处注入后, 就可以通过DA_SERVICE_TOKEN获取被注入的类型.
            { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: SimpleInterceptor, multi: true },
            { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: DefaultInterceptor, multi: true },
            { provide: ALAIN_I18N_TOKEN, useClass: I18NService, multi: false },
            StartupService,
            ReuseTabService,
            {
                provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
                useFactory: StartupServiceFactory,
                deps: [StartupService],
                multi: true
            }
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { 
    constructor(private logger: Logger) {
        this.logger.level = environment.logger.Level;
    }
    }
```

How to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is just because you are executing some code in forRoot, you shoud remove :

```
const _NZ_MESSAGE_CONFIG = {
        nzDuration: 1500,
        nzMaxStack: 1,
        nzPauseOnHover: true,
        nzAnimate: true
    };
```

And recode with inline declaration:

```
{ provide: NZ_MESSAGE_CONFIG, useValue: {
                                        nzDuration: 1500,
                                        nzMaxStack: 1,
                                        nzPauseOnHover: true,
                                        nzAnimate: true  } },
```